# nullPointerException Help (android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Im new to androiod coding. Ive only ever published one app which was a simple piano. Im trying to make a flash card app for studying but it keep crashing. When I debug I get a nullPointerException which Im not exactly sure what it means. Here is my code(I dont understand how to post code):

```
package com.example.hostoryflashcards;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{
String classes[] = {
        "Usa", "Canada", "New Mexico", "Other3", "Other4", "Other5"
};
String answer[] = {
        "Washington DC", "Ottowa", "Santa fae"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Button b1;
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(position);
    b1.setText("test");

}
```

}

Whats my problem?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Please post logcat output, otherwise it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: you are missing the "setContentView" call on the onCreate to inflate the views, then after trying to get a reference of the button(or any other view), you get null and then the crash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say where your `NullPointerException` is, but I imagine the issue is that in:

```
b1 = (Button)findViewById(position);
b1.setText("test");
```

`b1 == Null`, so when you do `b1.setText("test")` you get a `NullPointerException`.

**Edit:**

As @Martin Cazares pointed out:

> "you are missing the "setContentView" call on the onCreate to inflate
>   the views, then after trying to get a reference of the button(or any
>   other view), you get null and then the crash..."

Comment: @user2946774 After you call `onCreate()`, you need to call `setContentView()`, and pass it the view that you want to set.

Comment: I used setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and It crashed. Im sorry im not understanding. Im a self taught 13 year old programmer :/ I have pretty much no idea what im doing.

Comment: @user2946774 Here's a pretty good book that should help you: [Professional Android 4 Application Development](http://lecturer.eepis-its.edu/~yuliana/Android/Buku/professional_android_4_application_development.pdf).  I know you're young and fairly new to programming, but the best way to learn is to read and implement, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say if your layout file named activity_main.xml

Simply add this code under your super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And there you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   TextView textView = (TextView)v;
   textView.setText("test");
}
```